# How to use ifelse to make a new variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having trouble running this code (Part B) with ifelse. I keep getting an error "Unused arguments". I know there are other questions like this with answers and I saw them, but I can't figure out what my mistake is. My code is below. Any help is appreciated; I am very new to R.

```
#Question 3
#First make the dataframe
Age <- c(12, 12, 13, 13, 12, 13)
Quiz <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'F', 'B')
Midterm <- c(92, 88, 78, 92, 55, 88)
Final <- c(95, 88, 75, 93, 50, 82)
School <- data.frame(Age, Quiz, Midterm, Final)
#Part A:
School$Grade <- ifelse(School$Age == 12, 6, 8)
#Part B:
School$QuizGrade <- 
  ifelse(
    (School$Quiz == 'A'),
    95, 
    ifelse(School$Quiz == 'B'), 
    85, 
    ifelse(School$Quiz == 'C'), 
    75, 
    ifelse(School$Quiz == 'D'), 
    70, 
    65)
View(School)
```

Comment: `ifelse` takes three arguments: the conditional (`Quiz=="A"`), the "yes" and the "no" vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
School <- School %>%
    mutate(QuizGrade = case_when(Quiz == 'A' ~ 95
                        Quiz == 'B' ~ 85,
                         Quiz == 'C' ~ 75,
                          Quiz == 'D' ~ 70, TRUE ~ 65))
```

---

Or use a join with key/value dataset

```
library(tidyr)
key_val <- data.frame(Quiz = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), QuizGrade = c(95, 85, 75, 70))
School %>%
     left_join(key_val) %>% 
      mutate(QuizGrade = replace_na(QuizGrade, 65))
```

---

In the OP's code, the `ifelse` closing parentheses should be at the end instead of prematurely closing it at the `test` condition itself i.e. the Usage is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

OP's code was basically doing

```
ifelse(test)
```

and leaving out the 'yes', 'no' arguments

If we want to make use `ifelse`, the nested case would look more like

```
ifelse(
   School$Quiz == 'A', # // 1st test condition
   95,  # 1st yes value
    ifelse(School$Quiz == 'B', # // no case - 2nd test condition,
    85, # // 2nd yes value
      ifelse(School$Quiz == 'C', # // no case - 3rd test condition
       75, # // 3rd yes value
         ifelse(School$Quiz == 'D', # // no case - 4th test condition
         70, # // yes 
           65)))) # // no value and closing all parentheses
#[1] 95 85 75 95 65 85
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am practicing using if-else and ifelse functions. These are very good tips, but I would like to know how to do this step using if-else or ifelse.

Comment: @hazel updated the post with ifelse

Comment: @hazel I think part of the reason was that in the first ifelse you started with enclosing bracket around the logical expression, but in the following nested ones, you forgot the `(`, but it was closing the `ifelse` itself. The 'test' condition shows only a single logical expression, so wrapping within the `()` wouldn't make any difference in terms of precedence of operators